# Why does Directory.GetFiles() run faster on subsequent runs?

Tags: c#, performance, caching, execution

I'm not really sure what causes this so please forgive me if I couldn't find the information I needed in a search. Here is an example:

Let's say that we have a folder with 1,000,000 files. Running Directory.GetFiles() on that will take a few minutes.  However, running it again right after will take only a few seconds.  Why does this happen?  Are the objects being cached somewhere?  How can I run it with the original time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard drives have internal caches that will help speed up subsequent reads. Try reading a bunch of other directory information in a completely different sector to clear the cache.

Comment: So it's not .NET optimizations, but rather the HD?

Comment: It is possible that the operating system is caching it as well in RAM. It is hard to say exactly which cache level is making your read so quick on the second pass.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which it is? How can I know which directories are in a different sector so I can test that out?

Comment: I'm not so knowledgeable about that lower level stuff. If you want to cache some stuff in a different sector, read some really large files (couple of gigs) into memory and just toss the data as you churn through it.