# Why is a Flash drive slower in the first run?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Directory.GetFiles() run faster on subsequent runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519374/why-does-directory-getfiles-run-faster-on-subsequent-runs)

I'm running code that gets all of the `DirectoryInfo`'s (recursively) in a folder on a flash drive. The first time it's run after the drive is inserted takes around 15~18 seconds. On subsequent runs - around 5~6 seconds. This is both if I run it immediately after inserting the drive, or if I wait around 45 seconds before running.

What's the reason for the difference?

Comment: Could it be an antivirus delaying access to the file during your first-read?

Comment: The operating system is caching the folder information.

Comment: anytime doing the same thing twice is faster the second time the immediate thought should be "caching".  After that it's simply a matter of what is cached, how big the cache is, and when do cached items expire.  In this case, my guess is the OS is caching the file system data, but there could be other things cached as well with varying levels of contribution to the result.

Comment: Note that the reason the speed difference is so different from the duplicate target is because flash drive is so much quicker than a disk for cache misses.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But how would the operating system know if the values changed from last time by some other computer? (Or is that impossible with a flash drive?)

Comment: Because it is the operating system.  Any requests to change data on that flash drive would have to go through your OS.

Comment: @ispiro The drive itself will be storing information about the last time it was modified, and the cache knows the time it was populated.  It's *much* quicker to just compare the two dates and be done than to fetch the entire file from the drive again.

Comment: @Servy "duplicate target" - you mean the other question?